# Arbitrary subgroup or kernel?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have encountered this problem in Michael Artin's Algebra and it's unclear to me if the $K$ stands for an arbitrary subgroup or the kernel.Thanks!

Prove that the intersection $K\cap H$ of subgroups of a group $G$ is a subgroup of $H$, and that if $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $K\cap H$ is a normal subgroup of $H$.

Comment: It stands for an ordinary subgroup - no homomorphism is specified, so it cannot be a kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Every normal subgroup is the kernel of *some* map, and every kernel is a normal subgroup. In this setting it stands for a subgroup which is normal.

It is conceptually helpful to think of it as a kernel, maybe that is why they write it that way: $G \to G/K$ has kernel $K$, then the restriction of this map to the subgroup $H$ has kernel $H \cap K$ (think of which things go to zero). So $H \cap K$ is normal in $H$.